# GRE subject exam advice

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

So, I would like to ask those of you who have had this experience for some advice.

1. What book is best for GRE subject exam? I have noticed that some books online have mistakes, so I would like if you can give me specific publisher for GRE subject exam in physics book.
2. I would appreciate any advice on how to prepare for it. How to get best out of my studying period?

Comment: The other question is just about general subject-specific physics books, not about books specifically geared towards what you need for the GRE, so I don't see how this can be called a duplicate.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate??? @qmechanic

Comment: Hi beyondtheory. Phys.SE only allows a limited number of prerequisite and study advice questions, because they tend to be e.g. _primarily opinion-based_ and _too broad._ I'm closing this a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Comment: ok I understand your point. @Qmechanic